# Want to update fragment view after receiving data from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to update my pie chart view when i recieve a call back from another fragment through an interface. So basically what I am trying to achieve is that when the other fragment sends over the data to my fragment, the my fragment should update it's view accordingly. The interface method is RecieveCalorieDistribution.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nutrition_goals_for_today, container, false);

    View child=CreatePieChart();
    LinearLayout view=(LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PieChartContainer);
    view.addView(child);


    return rootView;
}
public void RecieveCalorieDistribution(int carbs,int fats,int proteins)
{
    this.carbs=carbs;
    this.fats=fats;
    this.proteins=proteins;
    float total=carbs+fats+proteins;
    this.carbs=(this.carbs/total)*100;
    this.fats=(this.fats/total)*100;
    this.proteins=(this.proteins/total)*100;

}
private View CreatePieChart() {

      // Pie Chart Section Names
      String[] code = new String[] { "Carbohydrates", "Fat","Protein" };

      // Pie Chart Section Value
      double[] distribution = { (int)carbs, (int)fats, (int)proteins};

      // Color of each Pie Chart Sections
      int[] colors = { Color.parseColor("#AFDCEC"),Color.parseColor("#FFF380"), Color.parseColor("#6CBB3C") };//blue,yellow,green

      // Instantiating CategorySeries to plot Pie Chart
      CategorySeries distributionSeries = new CategorySeries(
        "Mobile Platforms");
      for (int i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
       // Adding a slice with its values and name to the Pie Chart
       distributionSeries.add(code[i], distribution[i]);
      }
      // Instantiating a renderer for the Pie Chart
      DefaultRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
      for (int i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
       SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
       seriesRenderer.setColor(colors[i]);
       seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
       // Adding a renderer for a slice
       defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
      }
      defaultRenderer.setLegendTextSize(30);
      defaultRenderer.setLegendHeight(45);
      defaultRenderer.setChartTitle("Calories Distribution");
      defaultRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);

      defaultRenderer.setShowLabels(false);
      defaultRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
      defaultRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
      defaultRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(19);
      defaultRenderer.setDisplayValues(true);
      defaultRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);



      View view=ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getActivity(), distributionSeries, defaultRenderer);

      return view;



     }

public class NutritionGoalsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

 private NutritionGoalsForTodayFragment todayFragment;
 private NutritionGoalsSummaryFragment summaryFragment;

public NutritionGoalsFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    todayFragment=new NutritionGoalsForTodayFragment();
    summaryFragment=new NutritionGoalsSummaryFragment();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
       return todayFragment;


    case 1:
    {

       return summaryFragment;
    }

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 2;
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you using fragments? Isn't the pie chart just a view that you add to a layout? If you have a fragment in a layout, you can load a pie chart view in. And then when new data comes you can swap out the fragment for a new one.

Comment: Yes i want to make an new pie chart when the interface call backs from NutritionGoalsSummaryFragment, how do I do it?

Comment: Im not sure if this is the best way, but here is an idea: Assuming ReceiveCalorieDistribution is the function called with new data. Have a new pie chart view created. Then find the piechart container and call view.removeAllViews() then just add the new view

Comment: Will your solution work? call the view.removeAllViews() in onCreateView()? How did I find the piechart container? Sorry i am not an expert here.

Comment: Can you post an answer in terms of code so that I can understand you properly.

Comment: Yes, give me a few minutes. I'm just working through some code. Havent done android in awhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have found the solution after thoroughly understanding your comment.

```
public void RecieveCalorieDistribution(int carbs,int fats,int proteins)
{
    this.carbs=carbs;
    this.fats=fats;
    this.proteins=proteins;
    float total=carbs+fats+proteins;
    this.carbs=(this.carbs/total)*100;
    this.fats=(this.fats/total)*100;
    this.proteins=(this.proteins/total)*100;
    View view=CreatePieChart();
    LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PieChartContainer);
    linear.removeAllViews();
    linear.addView(view);
}
```

Comment: Yes does this work? I wasn't sure if you could use findViewById outside of onCreate. Thought you might have to make a variable in main.

Comment: Yes I had to create a variable at class level of this Fragment and yes it is working.